# Incrementing PK column from specific number(PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment

In my PostgreSQL database I have table `users` which has two columns, `PK named uid(serial)` and `user_type(integer)`. Is it possible that for regular users (of user_type 1) **uid starts from 0** (and increments regularly), and for non-regular users (of user_type 2), **uid starts from (let's say) 5000**, and to increments from that number (5000, 5001, 5002...) each time new non-regular user is added?

I won't have more than 2000 regular users, so overlap between uids of regular and non-regular users will never happen.

Comment: You are putting a meaning into a primary key - a very bad idea - especially because you are "duplicating" the information that is already available in the `user_type` column.

Comment: I am not doing this so I can make difference between regular and non-regular users. For that I have user_type column. I am doing this because I will have to fetch users from different database, and keep their uid, and write them in mine. So, if I have(in mine db) non-regular user with uid 1500, and I am fetching regular user from different database who also have uid 1500 there will be error and I won't be able to insert that regular user...

Comment: Consider using a GUID instead then.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good idea, I'll put some useful links for that in my answer

Answer (score 4):

A `serial` data type will create a sequence and pull the default value for your column out of that sequence. For what you're trying to do you'd need two sequences, pull from these sequences and insert the `uid` explicitly. This is not something the `serial` can *nor should* do.

To echo @a_horse_with_no_name, you shouldn't put information into a `serial` data type. A generated primary key is only acceptable if it is completely opaque to the table users. Please consider just letting `serial` do its work and update your application code to react properly to `user_type`. Since your concern seems to be id collision with external entities, I'd suggest storing the user ids generated by an external system in a separate field, say `extern_uid`.

Or have the external system generate [UUID](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-uuid.html) strings you can safely use in your `uid` column. If the external system is a PostgresSQL database as well, you might use the [uuid-ossp module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/uuid-ossp.html) to generate the UUID/GUID.

If you absolutely *have* to use sequences, you'd need to:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE uid_one START 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE uid_two START 5000;

INSERT INTO user (uid, user_type) VALUES (nextval('uid_one'::regclass), 1);
INSERT INTO user (uid, user_type) VALUES (nextval('uid_two'::regclass), 2);
```

Selecting the appropiate statement is left to the application.

Comment: So, I can have two sequences for one PK column(uid)?
Can you please show me a piece of code or something...

Comment: @anagarD I've updated the answer, but please consider alternatives to your table design.

Comment: @anagarD: well you *could* use two sequences to populate the column from inside a trigger. But again: that is a very bad idea.

Comment: Problem is that table 'user' is main table for my app, and I can't add any other column, and every user must be stored in that table. External users will be of user_type 3. 
External system is MySQL db.

Comment: And I also must add that column uid must be number(referring to UUID).

Comment: @anagarD Well, then using two sequences seems to be your only option. You can use a [trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtrigger.html) to ease the selection burden, but be warned that maintaining this setup will be a continued nightmare.